# $g(x)=x+f(x)$ defined on $\mathbb{R}^n$ where $f$ is 1/2-lipschitz. Prove that g is an homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology, lipschitz-functions

Let $f : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ an application such that for every $x, y \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq\frac{1}{2}|x-y|$. Let $g : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ defined by $g(x)=x+f(x)$

Prove that $g$ is an homeomorphism.

Note : 
$g$  is continuous, because it's the sum of two continuous function. For all $x,y, \frac{1}{2}|x−y|≤|g(x)−g(y)|≤\frac{3}{2}|x−y|$. This implies $g$ is injection, and the image by $g$ of an open set is an open set. It remains to prove $g$ surjection

Source : quiz in topology course

Comment: Any thoughts?${}$

Comment: @曾靖國 Can you edit this into your original post instead of leaving it as a comment?

Comment: By the way, this theorem is known as "invariance of domain."

Comment: @Math1000 if using the theorem that you mentioned above, we still need to prove $g$ surjection, no? My teacher told us we need to use Banach fixed point theorem for that, or do you have other suggestion? P.S. we haven't learned "invariance of domain" yet.

Answer (score 1):

$g$  is continuous, because it's the sum of two continuous function. For all $x,y, \frac{1}{2}|x−y|≤|g(x)−g(y)|≤\frac{3}{2}|x−y|$. This implies $g$ is injection, and the image by $g$ of an open set is an open set.

It remains to prove $g$ surjection :

Let $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$. $t \in \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow f(y-t) \mathbb{R}^n$ is $\frac{1}{2}$-lipschitz function. By Banach fixed point theorem, there is $m \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $m = f(y-m)$. Then $g(y-m) = y-m + f(y-m) = y$. So $g$ is surjective.